# compare a header value between two .csv file if match is found then add a column with corresponding value using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I seen this kind of posts but couldn't able to get exact working module. I hope someone can help me on this.

I have two .CSV files

### **file1.csv**

"ID","status","Type"

"mzx1","Active","A"

"mzx2","Active","B"

"mzx3","Active","C"

### **file2.csv**

"ID","User Company","Date"

"mzx1","MS","2020-01-01"

"mzx3","Sam","020-01-01"

"mzx5","new","020-01-03"

I need to compare the ID value in *file2.csv* file if it matches then add a column with value "User Company"

### **file3.csv**

"ID","status","Type","Company"

"mzx1","Active","A","MS"

"mzx2","Active","B","Not found"

"mzx3","Active","C","Sam"

Now if you see the example of **file3.csv** file which has all the rows of **file1.csv** file and new column "Company". As well for no ID match found it  should draft "Not found".

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$File1 | LeftJoin $File2 -on ID -Property ID,status,Type,@{Company = {$Right.'User Company'}}`

Answer (score 0):

This example show how to add property to a csv $file1 variable:

```
$file1 = @'
"ID","status","Type"
"mzx1","Active","A"
"mzx2","Active","B"
"mzx3","Active","C"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$file2 = @'
"ID","User Company","Date"
"mzx1","MS","2020-01-01"
"mzx3","Sam","020-01-01"
"mzx5","new","020-01-03"
'@| ConvertFrom-Csv


foreach($l in $file1){
    $l2 = $file2 | Where { $_.ID -eq $l.ID }
    if ($l2 )
    {
        $l | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'User Company' -Value $l2.'User Company'
    }
    else
    {
        $l | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'User Company' -Value 'Not found'
    }
}
$file1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated property with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) in this PowerShell v4+ solution:

```
$file1 = Import-Csv file1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv file2.csv
$file3 = foreach ($row in $file1) {
    $lookup = $file2.Where({$_.ID -eq $row.ID},'First')
    $row | Select *,@{n='Company';e={if ($lookup) { $lookup.'User Company' } else { 'Not Found'}}}
}
$file3 | Export-Csv file3.csv -NoType
```

Comment: @BalaKrishna, please consider marking the answer (green checkbox) if you feel this answered your question. This helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the -AsHashTable property of Group-Object to create a lookup table and combine with calculated properties.

```
$file1 = @'
"ID","status","Type"
"mzx1","Active","A"
"mzx2","Active","B"
"mzx3","Active","C"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$file2 = @'
"ID","User Company","Date"
"mzx1","MS","2020-01-01"
"mzx3","Sam","020-01-01"
"mzx5","new","020-01-03"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | group -Property id -AsHashTable

$file1 | select *,@{n='Company';e={$(if($file2[$_.id]){$file2[$_.id].'User Company'}else{'Not Found'})}}
```

Output as expected

```
ID   status Type Company  
--   ------ ---- -------  
mzx1 Active A    MS       
mzx2 Active B    Not Found
mzx3 Active C    Sam
```

Could look a lot neater

```
$file1 = @'
"ID","status","Type"
"mzx1","Active","A"
"mzx2","Active","B"
"mzx3","Active","C"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$file2 = @'
"ID","User Company","Date"
"mzx1","MS","2020-01-01"
"mzx3","Sam","020-01-01"
"mzx5","new","020-01-03"
'@| ConvertFrom-Csv | group -Property id -AsHashTable

$company = {
    Param($ID)

    $out = $file2[$ID].'User Company'
    if($out){$out} else {'Not Found'}
}

$file1 | select *,@{n='Company';e={& $company $_.id}} | Export-Csv $file3 -NoTypeInformation
```